# How could one determine that required argument of option is missing?

Tags: c, linux, getopt-long, command-line-arguments

I use `getopt_long` on GNU/Linux machine.
Initialize options list as:

```
static struct option long_options[] = {
     {"mode", required_argument, 0, 9},
     {0, 0, 0, 0}
};
```

Have following line of code

```
c = getopt_long(argc, argv, "", long_options, index_ptr);
```

When I run my program with command:

```
prog --mode
```

Above shown line of code returns '?' in c, but not ':' as expected according to `getopt(3)` man page: *"Error and -1 returns are the
       same as for getopt()"*

Yes, when using/parsing short options one could write in options list something like ":m:", so that variable *c* on missing argument would contain ':', not '?', but what one should do to distinguish between two cases(missing argument, invalid option) when parsing *only* long options?

**How could one distinguish between invalid option and option with missing required argument?**

Comment: Why in the `long_options` array you have used 9 as val to be returned instead of a character '9' and why the `optstring/shortopts` parameter is not containing "9:" ? (see [Example of Parsing Long Options](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt-Long-Option-Example.html#Getopt-Long-Option-Example))

Comment: @DavidBowling `.val` is an `int`, but mainly to be used when the `.flag` pointer is not NULL. Because `9` is could not be used to detect a shortcut argument, it is better to use a character like `'m'` (for mode).

Comment: Yes, I read getopt[_long] section of glibc reference manual before asking the question. But it is not clear what should be returned in that case.

Comment: @Piquard, it does not really matter what they return, because I want to distinguish two error cases(missing argument, invalid option) and I want to parse only long options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way that I can see to accomplish your goal of distinguishing between an invalid option and a valid option with a missing argument is to set the `has_arg` field of the options struct to `optional_argument`, and then to test manually for an argument. Then `getopt_long()` will only return a value of '?' when there is an invalid option, and you can check to see if a specified option has an argument by looking in `optarg`. Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <getopt.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, opt;
    int index = -1;

    static struct option long_options[] = {
        {"mode", optional_argument, NULL, 'm'},
        {0, 0, 0, 0}
    };

    /* suppress error messages */
    //opterr = 0;

    while ((opt = getopt_long(argc, argv, "", long_options, &index)) != -1) {
        if (opt == '?') {
            /* do something, perhaps: */
            //printf("Invalid option \n");
            //      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (opt == 'm' && optarg == NULL) {
            printf("Missing argument in '--mode' option\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }        
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I thought about it too, the issue is that the body with if conditionals will grow if one has a lot of options like --mode.

Comment: @BulatM.-- have you considered using [Argp](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argp.html#Argp)? It looks a bit more involved than the `getopt`-style functions, but it looks more flexible. It might be able to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

It is really a bummer that GNU getopt doesn't just return `:` in that case :( It got *so* close to get it right but [explicitly tests if there is a `:` in the short args string](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=posix/getopt.c;hb=dd858522bf36ae16496ea01ff8b65e16b4e5c22b#l364).

In my alternative solution I exploit that `optopt` is set to the respective `val`. This solves the issue with printing a generalized message for missing option arguments but somehow feels dirty. I have not tested this too much, beware. It does not correctly handle inputs with single `-`.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <getopt.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    static int req, opt;
    static struct option long_options[] = {
        {"req_flag", required_argument, &req, 1},
        {"opt_flag", optional_argument, &opt, 1},
        {"req", required_argument, NULL, 'r'},
        {"opt", optional_argument, NULL, 'o'},
        {"none", no_argument, NULL, 'n'},
        {0, 0, 0, 0}
    };

    /* suppress getopt's own error messages */
    opterr = 0;

    int c, option_index;
    while ((c = getopt_long(argc, argv, "", long_options, &option_index)) != -1) {
        printf("c=%c (%x), option_index=%d, optind=%d, optopt=%c (%x), optarg='%s'\n",
            c, c, option_index, optind, optopt, optopt, optarg);
        switch (c) {
            case 0:
                if (optarg != NULL) {
                    printf("flag for %s was set to %d (optarg=%s)\n",
                        long_options[option_index].name, *long_options[option_index].flag, optarg);
                    // the flag's value is probably useless in the case of req_flag because
                    // if it is required you probably want to change behavior depending
                    // on the value of optarg and not just its presence :)
                    // That (and also handling of optarg of optional flags) would need to
                    // be done here depending on option_index. I wouldn't recommend using this.
                } else {
                    printf("flag for %s was set to %d\n",
                        long_options[option_index].name, *long_options[option_index].flag);
                }
                break;
            case 'r':
                printf("%s=%s\n", long_options[option_index].name, optarg);
                break;
            case 'o':
                if (optarg == NULL) {
                    printf("%s given w/o argument\n", long_options[option_index].name);
                } else {
                    printf("%s=%s\n", long_options[option_index].name, optarg);
                }
                break;
            case '?':
                if (optopt == 0) {
                    printf("Invalid option: %s\n", argv[optind-1]);
                } else {
                    printf("Missing argument for long option %s\n", argv[optind-1]);
                }
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```